# How to prevent illegal characters error in DB2 SQL query?

Tags: regex, db2, illegal-characters

I'm working with a huge DB2 table (hundreds of millions of rows), trying to select only the rows that are matched by this regular expression:

```
\b\d([- \/\\]?\d){12,15}(\D|$)
```

(That is, a word boundary, followed by 13 to 16 digits separated by nothing or a single dash, space, slash, or backslash, followed be either a non-digit or the end of the line.)

After much Googling, I've managed to create the following SQL:

```
SELECT idx, comment FROM tblComment
WHERE xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:matches($c,"\b\d([- \/\\]?\d){12,15}(\D|$)")' PASSING comment AS "c") AS INTEGER)=1
```

Which works perfectly, as far as I can tell... unless it finds a row with an illegal character:

> An illegal XML character "#x3" was found in an SQL/XML expression or function argument that begins with string [...]

The data contains many illegal XML characters, and changing the data is not an option (I have limited read-only access, and there are far too many rows that would need to be fixed). Is there a way to strip out or ignore illegal characters, without first modifying the database? Or, is there a different way for me to write my query that has the same effect?

Comment: What is your database's codepage?

Comment: I... have no idea. I'm a DB2 noob, plus I have no control and very little access to the database. Is there a query I can run to find out? I can run it once I'm back in the office tomorrow morning.

Comment: codeset and codepage could be queried like this   select * from sysibmadm.dbcfg where name like 'code%'    otherwise ask your DBA

Comment: Codepage: 1252; codeset: IBM-1252

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to identify what are all the illegal XML characters that occur in your data. Once you know them, you can use the `TRANSLATE()` function to eliminate them during the pattern matching.

Say, you determine that all ASCII control characters (0x00 through 0x0F and 0x7F) may be present in the `COMMENT` column. Your query might then look like:

```
SELECT idx, comment FROM tblComment
WHERE xmlcast(xmlquery(
  'fn:matches($c,"\b\d([- \/\\]?\d){12,15}(\D|$)")' 
  PASSING TRANSLATE(comment, ' ', x'01020304050607080B0C0F7F') AS "c") 
AS INTEGER)=1
```

All *legal* XML characters are [listed in the manual](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql20377n.html). 0x09, 0x0A and 0x0D are legal, so you don't need to `TRANSLATE()` them, for example.